# How to get exactly the same keyboard layout in Windows as in macOS?

Tags: macos, windows-10, keyboard-layout

I am using macOS on my MacBook Pro but for different reasons I do also have to use Windows 10 to make some programming now and then. I would like to use exactly the same keyboard layout in Windows and I have not found a good solution yet.

My main problems with Windows keyboard are:

- the `{` and `}` is at a different place, which I just can not handle. I want them to be where they are on OSX.
- I want to use <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> etc… in Windows as I would use them in macOS.

Is there a program to change this? I really just want the macOS standard to work in Windows.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the { and } are at a different place? I'm currently using a Mac with a Windows keyboard, and the { } are the shift characters for [ ], which are just to the right of p on both keyboards.

Comment: I realized that this is a language specific problem. I am using a swedish keyboard where those are not the same in osx and Windows.

Comment: Alright, makes sense. I added an answer that I think addresses those things.

Comment: Are you aware of the [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx)? It is not officially supporting Windows 8/10, but I got it to work under Windows 8, so I suppose it should work under Windows 10 as well. You can use it to create arbitrary keyboard layouts.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Windows 10 version 1903 or higher, I would suggest using [PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys) by Microsoft. The following answer provides the full details https://superuser.com/a/1588228/1306677

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you want is to be able swap a couple keys in Windows 10. [SharpKeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys) should be able to do this.

Specifically, you'll want to swap around whatever the curly braces are, and swap alt with ctrl: alt is in the same position as the command key on a Mac keyboard, and swapping it with ctrl makes ctrl-V/C/X the same motion as command-V/C/X.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to get this work with AutoHotKey. This is more complex to configure than MS PowerToys, but allows far more options, e.g. send an ASC character based on a specific key click (in comparison, PowerToys only allows to switch key shortcut to a different key shortcut - which on Czech keyboard e.g. means the key for `^` cannot be created, as the only option to write this via keyboard is `AltGr + 3` - but this is written as an accent (=dead key), which is not really sufficient.

My aim was slightly different (I wanted a Czech Mac layout on a Windows machine) but the approach to handle this is the same.

A few representative examples:

```
<^>!sc003::@
<^>!sc007::
Send {ASC 094}
return
<^>!sc00A::{
<^>!sc00B::}
+sc02B::
Send {ASC 096}
return
```

The example configures:

- RAlt + scancode 003 (that is the key with number `2` on most keyboards, with character `ě` on Czech keyboard) to `@` sign
- RAlt + scancode 007 (key with number `6` on most keyboards) to `^` sign
- RAlt + scancode 00A and 00B (keys with numbers `9` and `0`) to `{` and `}`
- Shift + key 02B (the one next to Enter) to the grave accent sign

Similarly you can remap other keys and combinations to other variants. See [AutoHotKey website](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

- Access "Time & Language" in Windows settings
- Access "Language" tab
- Click on your language (mine is "English - United States")
- Click on "Options"
- Click on "Add a keyboard"
- Choose "United States - International"

When I type `'` + `c` I got `ç`
When I type ` + `e` I got `è`
When I type `'` + `e` I got `é`

Just like in MacOS

Answer (score -3):

The french braces are in the same position on both keyboards.  If you would like to switch the [command] and [option] keys on OS X so that they match the position (and behavior) of the [windows] and [alt] keys on a Windows keyboard, start from the Finder in OS X

1. Apple Menu
2. Systems Preferences...
3. Keyboard
4. Keyboard tab
5. [Modifier Keys...] button in lower right

Use the drop-down menus located in this window to specify the action of each of the modifier keys ([caps lock], [control], [option],and [command]).

Comment: I would like to change in Windows, not in osx.