# How to overwrite Windows Snipping Tool hotkey?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Windows Snipping Tool (for screenshots) is using the [Windows} +{Shift] +[S] key.

I have uninstalled it but it's still coming up when I press that key.

I want to use that hotkey for another (third party) screenshot tool.

When I try (in Snagit 2019) to assign {Windows} + [Shift} S as the shorcut (which you do by pressing the keys) the Windows Snipping Tool comes up and the keyboard combo does not get assigned to Snagit.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would expect that installing the third party app and telling it to use that hotkey should cause the new app to hook the keys. does it not? does the third party app provide any guidance on how to do it? Personally I use PrntScrn for my 3rd party screenshot tool.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the Windows ALT+TAB hotkey to something else?](https://superuser.com/questions/543971/how-to-change-the-windows-alttab-hotkey-to-something-else)

Comment: That's not a duplicate. But voting to close as basic info such as system version or how it was uninstalled is missing.

Comment: When I try (in Snagit 2019) to assign {Windows} + [Shift} S as the shorcut (which you do by pressing the keys) the Windows Snipping Tool comes up and the keyboard combo does not get assigned to Snagit.

Comment: in snagit, did you check the box "**Allow Snagit to override other hotkey assignments**" ? https://www.techsmith.com/learn/tutorials/snagit/snagit-hotkeys/